# How can i find out the current quarter's start date for a given date in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to find out the first date of the current quarter for a given date. So how can I do that?

Comment: Did you have done any research about your problem? Do you have any code to show your efforts? Just asking _gimme teh codez_ is not very appreciated here

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean calendar quarters that start on the first of January and every three months thereafter, you can use `datefromparts()`:

```
select datefromparts(year(@date), 1 + (month(@date) - 1) / 3, 1)
```

`datefromparts()` is available in SQL Server 2012+.  You can do something similar in earlier versions by constructing the date as a string.

For the *current* quarter, use `getdate()` instead of `@date`.